# Invoke Toast in an external class

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I have an external class and I want to use Toast in this class.
I tried to implement this but I get an error.

How can I do this in easy way without any error?

```
public class ElevenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @
  Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eleven);
  }

  public class MyToast {
    public MyToast(String message) {
      Toast.makeText(ElevenActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}

public class externalClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  public void CreateDB() {
    ElevenActivity.MyToast t = new ElevenActivity.MyToast("Here");
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?  please add it to the question

Comment: thanks for your help , i fixed the problem by passing context to the external class

Answer (score 0):

Just make a Toast in the external class using getApplicationContext(). Like,

```
public class externalClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public void CreateDB() {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but i got error too , but i fixed thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a method which should be valid for different contexts (e.g. activities), pass this context as parameter.

```
public static void textToast(String textToDisplay, Context context)  { ... }
```

If you want to call this method from nested inner classes (as is often the case), you can use this as context

```
public void textToast(String textToDisplay) {
    ...
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(OuterClass.this, text, duration);
    ...
}
```

(or implement textToast in the outer class and call it via OuterClass.this.textToast from the nested inner class)
..........

Comment: thanks for sharing another way to implement this case